# Subgroups of a Galois group $G$

Tags: galois-theory

I have the following exercise:

> $L$ is a finite Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group $G$ (that is $G=Gal(L/K)$). Suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ are subextensions and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the respective subgroups of $G$. Show that $G$ is a direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$ iff $L_1$ and $L_2$ are Galois extensions of $K$ s.t. $L_1 L_2 =L$ and $L_1 \cap L_2 =K$

What I am just wondering is the respective subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$. If $G_1$ was Galois extension is $G_1=\operatorname{Gal}(L_1 /K)$ or is $G_1 =\operatorname{Gal}(L/L_1)$? I guessed it was the latter based on theorems for example the fundamental theorem of Galois extensions in the finite case but based on [this](http://planetmath.org/galoisgroupofthecompositumoftwogaloisextensions). And is true that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are in general Galois extensions?

Comment: The latter, yes. And $L/L_i$ is always a Galois extension. It's $L_i/K$ that may not be a Galois extension.

Comment: $L_1$ is not Galois since its not normal Dustan.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, what's the problem? In that case $\;L_1/\Bbb Q\;$ is **not** Galois...

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part of the assertion.

Comment: But are u sure about it is the latter because $L_1$ and $L_2$ are Galois extensions of K and based on the link I gave it has the form $Gal(L/K)$.

Comment: Yes. There's no conflict with the result you linked to, because when $G$ is the direct product of $G_1$ and $G_2$, we have $G_1 \simeq G/G_2 = \operatorname{Gal}(L_2/K)$ and $G_2 \simeq G/G_1 = \operatorname{Gal}(L_1/K)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints (and you try to connect the dots): If $\;G\;$ is a group and $\;N_1\,,\,N_2\le G\;$ , then:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;G=N_1\times N_2\iff\begin{cases}N_1,N_2\lhd G\\{}\\N_1N_2=G\\{}\\N_1\cap N_2=1\end{cases}\end{align*}$$

Now, using the Galois correspondence and theorems around this, and using your notation **and your assumptions**:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;G=G_1G_2\iff L_1L_2=L\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;G_i\lhd G\iff L_i/K\;\;\text{is a normal extension}\iff L_i/K\;\;\text{is Galois}\\{}\\\bullet&\;\;G_1\cap G_2=1\iff L_1\cap L_2=K\;\text{(hint: what extension fits to the trivial sbgp.?)}\end{align*}$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with that reversed play symbol. What does it mean in words?

Comment: @Raxel?? Do you mean $\;\lhd\;$ ? But that is the international symbol for *normal subgroup*: you **must** know basic group theory before engaging into Galois theory!

Comment: Well my lecture notes usually uses just words for it and Gallian does not use this symbol.

Comment: I don't know what Gallian book you're talking about, @Raxel, but if it is "Contemporary Abstract Algebra" he **does** use that symbol: 2nd edition, page 145, chapter 10. I really don't know *any* book in any language and after 1960 that doesn't use that symbol...not to mention that in a class at 2nd-3rd undergraduate level one usually knows already *several* books on some given subject.

Comment: Yes indeed that is the book I am using. I have seen the symbol and in the context it was probably clear what it meant. However my algebraic professor was studying the theory in the 60's in Germany and I believe that they did not use that symbol there at the time. At least he does not use it.

Comment: Well @Raxel, I don't even want to imagine what that prof's classes notes look like without using that so-important and widespread symbol: every time you need to write "normal subgroup"? Even chinese, russians, iranies, israelies (to mention just a few that I know directly of) use that symbol.

Comment: Indeed he does. Most of my professor use text rather than symbols and I think it is very readable.

Comment: Well, now you know one rather important symbol used, and it appears in *each and every* book in abstract algebra/ group theory as far as I recall, and it makes things way shorter and, imo, also simpler. Anyway, the answer's there and it doesn't change.